# Python BeautifulSoup extract contents from html file p tags which is in a group div tag. I am getting blank printed out

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract some data from my Selenium Test Report html file.
I am getting blank printed out to the PyCharm console.
I would like to get all the data from the P tag.  It is under a div tag.

The HTML snippet is:

```
<div class='heading'>
<h1>Test Report</h1>
<p class='attribute'><strong>Start Time:</strong> 2016-08-12 11:57:33</p>
<p class='attribute'><strong>Duration:</strong> 0:48:09.007000</p>
<p class='attribute'><strong>Status:</strong> Pass 75</p>

<p class='description'>Selenium - ClearCore 501 Regression edit project automated test</p>
</div>
```

As a start I have first tried to get the Start Time out and see if i can print the value to the console.  I am getting nothing printed out.
I would like to get the description out too, Selenium - ClearCore 501 Regression edit project automated test

My code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def extract_data_from_report_htmltestrunner():
    filename = (r"C:\share\ClearCore501_Automated_GUI_TestReport.html")
    html_report_part = open(filename,'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_report_part, "html.parser")
    div_heading = soup.find('div', {'class': 'heading'})
    p = div_heading.find('p', text='Start Time:')
    print "test"
    print p
```

I have added:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
extract_data_from_report_htmltestrunner()
```

The output I am now getting is:

```
test
None
```

What am i doing wrong please?

Thanks, Riaz

Comment: [*If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what .string should refer to, so .string is defined to be None*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is in the *strong* tag not the *p so find that and call *.parent* to get the *p* tag:

```
In [10]: html = """<div class='heading'>
   ....: <h1>Test Report</h1>
   ....: <p class='attribute'><strong>Start Time:</strong> 2016-08-12 11:57:33</p>
   ....: <p class='attribute'><strong>Duration:</strong> 0:48:09.007000</p>
   ....: <p class='attribute'><strong>Status:</strong> Pass 75</p>
   ....: 
   ....: <p class='description'>Selenium - ClearCore 501 Regression edit project automated test</p>
   ....: </div>"""

In [11]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [12]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

In [13]: div_heading = soup.find('div', {'class': 'heading'})

In [14]: p = div_heading.find('strong', text='Start Time:').parent

In [15]: print p
<p class="attribute"><strong>Start Time:</strong> 2016-08-12 11:57:33</p>
```

To get the description use the class name:

```
In [16]: div_heading.find("p", class_="description")
Out[16]: <p class="description">Selenium - ClearCore 501 Regression edit project automated test</p>
In [17]: div_heading.find("p", class_="description").text
Out[17]: u'Selenium - ClearCore 501 Regression edit project automated test'
```

If you just want the date, call *p.find(text=True, recursive=False)* so you don't get the text from any children.

```
In [18]: p = div_heading.find('strong', text='Start Time:').parent

In [19]: p.find(text=True, recursive=False)
Out[19]: u' 2016-08-12 11:57:33'
In [20]: p.text
Out[20]: u'Start Time: 2016-08-12 11:57:33'
```

You can see the difference above in both approaches. Just calling .text on the strong tag would just give you *u'Start Time:'*:

```
In [21]:  div_heading.find('strong', text='Start Time:').text
Out[21]: u'Start Time:'
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.  If i want to get the text Start Time: from the strong tag and it's value how can i do that.  My desired output would be "Start Time: 2016-08-12 11:57:33"

Comment: Would it be p.find(text=True, recursive=False)

Comment: @RiazLadhani, look at the second last code snippet, calling *p.text* gives you all the text including the text from the child, recursive=False only gets in from the parent.

Comment: Yes, just wanted to confirm.  Thank you for your help.